# Cohort in Firebase Analytics Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Good afternoon everyone,
I am not able to understand why 100% coming on March 4 and march 6.As there are 6 users on March 4 and 3 on March 6.Then why it is showing 100%.One more query,on March 6 day 1 and day 2 why it is 66.7% and 2 user.Please help me,facing a trouble in understanding cohort properly.

.[image]

Comment: I am new to cohort too, but you might want to check [this link](https://clevertap.com/blog/how-to-use-cohort-analysis-to-improve-customer-retention/), it helps me

Answer (score 0):

Day 0 is always 100% if there is at least single user; Day 2 shows what percentage of users returned on 2 days later